# How can I match single and double html attributes in regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have a html element with two different classes. but in some cases I have only one class. When there are two classes they are separated by space.

```
"rating-inbtn hide-if-zero-113"
 or 
"rating-inbtn"
```

How can I match both patterns in regular expression.

For reference I want to put an older post of mine :

```
<span class="vote-actions">
    <a class="btn btn-default vote-action-good">
        <span class="icon thumb-up black black-hover">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="rating-inbtn">215</span>
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-default vote-action-bad">
        <span class="icon thumb-down grey black-hover">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="rating-inbtn">82</span>
    </a>
</span>
```

and i was using this regular expression to extract the ratings

```
a = re.findall('rating-inbtn">(.*?)</span>', webpage)
        like_count = a[0]
        dislike_count = a[1]
```

But sometimes span class have more than one attributes "hide-if-zero-113" in that case how can I handle this pattern?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the boundaries you wish to add to an expression. For instance, we could start with:

```
\s*([a-z0-9-]+)(?:\s+)?([a-z0-9-]+)?\s*
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/JmJQba/1/), if you wish to explore further or modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/JmJQba/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.

---

Edit:

For capturing those ratings, this expression might simply suffice:

```
rating-inbtn[^>]+>\s*([^\s<]+)\s*<\/
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CJ8EAQ/1/)

#### Test with `re.findall`

```
import re

regex = r"rating-inbtn[^>]+>\s*([^\s<]+)\s*<\/"

test_str = ("<span class=\"vote-actions\">\n"
    "    <a class=\"btn btn-default vote-action-good\">\n"
    "        <span class=\"icon thumb-up black black-hover\">&nbsp;</span>\n"
    "        <span class=\"rating-inbtn\">215</span>\n"
    "    </a>\n"
    "    <a class=\"btn btn-default vote-action-bad\">\n"
    "        <span class=\"icon thumb-down grey black-hover\">&nbsp;</span>\n"
    "        <span class=\"rating-inbtn\">82</span>\n"
    "<span class=\"rating-inbtn\"> 74 </span>\n"
    "<span class=\"rating-inbtn hide-if-zero-113\"> 99 </span>\n"
    "    </a>\n"
    "</span>")

print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

#### Output

```
['215', '82', '74', '99']
```

#### Test with `re.finditer`

```
import re

regex = r"rating-inbtn[^>]+>\s*([^\s<]+)\s*<\/"

test_str = ("<span class=\"vote-actions\">\n"
    "    <a class=\"btn btn-default vote-action-good\">\n"
    "        <span class=\"icon thumb-up black black-hover\">&nbsp;</span>\n"
    "        <span class=\"rating-inbtn\">215</span>\n"
    "    </a>\n"
    "    <a class=\"btn btn-default vote-action-bad\">\n"
    "        <span class=\"icon thumb-down grey black-hover\">&nbsp;</span>\n"
    "        <span class=\"rating-inbtn\">82</span>\n"
    "<span class=\"rating-inbtn\"> 74 </span>\n"
    "<span class=\"rating-inbtn hide-if-zero-113\"> 99 </span>\n"
    "    </a>\n"
    "</span>")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

Comment: Dear @Emma Thanks for your reply. But I am a noob in regular expression. Doing some patch work. I have added some more context to my question. Can you please recheck my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing something, but you don't need regular expressions to extract the numbers from the code:

```
data = '''<span class="vote-actions">
    <a class="btn btn-default vote-action-good">
        <span class="icon thumb-up black black-hover">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="rating-inbtn">215</span>
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-default vote-action-bad">
        <span class="icon thumb-down grey black-hover">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="rating-inbtn">82</span>
    </a>
</span>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

print([span.text for span in soup.select('span.rating-inbtn')])
```

Prints:

```
['215', '82']
```

Answer (score 1):

I will expand upon one of the other answers given. In your lower examples, you are looking at two elements that both share the same single class which should be sufficient to match both elements. Your very top example shows a compound class (more than one class name for the element) but again this shares the same class of `rating-inbtn`.

```
soup.select('.rating-inbtn')
```

where the "." is a css class selector.

Expanding on the other answers:

In future you can pass lists separated by "," to match on more than one class (indeed more than one selector) e.g.

```
soup.select('.rating-inbtn, .otherClass')
```